# Can the preposition "pace" only be used for a parenthetical purpose?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Definition of [pace](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pace) from Merriam-Webster:

> **(Entry 3 of 3):** contrary to the opinion of — usually used as an expression of deference to someone's contrary opinion.

The MW provides the following example sentence, in which "pace" is used after a comma for a parenthetical purpose.

> - Easiness is a virtue in grammar, **pace** old-fashioned grammarians.

The English Oxford Living Dictionaries also provides the similar examples [sentences](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pace), like Merriam-Webster; the preposition "pace" is used for a parenthetical purpose:

> - ‘narrative history, **pace** some theorists, is by no means dead’
> - ‘And none of these - **pace** your earlier comments - have gimps, do they?’
> - ‘Legislation development services, **pace** my learned friend's submissions, clearly can include some forms of advertising.’

**My Question:** is this the only way to use the preposition "pace"? or there are uses of it other than using it merely for a parenthetical purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that’s the most common usage. From [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pace2):

Pace:

> used before a person’s name to express polite disagreement with what they have said:
>
> - The evidence suggests, pace Professor Jones, that… (= Professor Jones has a different opinion)

As noted in Etymonline, [Pace (prep.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pace):

> "with the leave of," 1863, from Latin pace, ablative of pax "peace," as in pace tua "with all deference to you;" from PIE root *pag- "to fasten." "***Used chiefly as a courteous or ironical apology for a contradiction or difference of opinion" [OED].***